# SQL Server CTE with Multiple Levels

Tags: sql-server

I've been playing around CTEs in SQL server but can't figure out how to accomplish this task.

I have table like so:

```
 ParentID, FolderID, Name

    1,      1,      Folder1

    1,      2,      Folder2

    1,      3,      Folder3

    2,      4,      Folder4

    ...

    198,    649,    Folder649
```

What I am trying to get to is:
Folder_Name, Folder_Path with \ in one line listing all folders up to the very parent

Example from above:
Folder4, Folder1\Folder2\Folder4

Is this possible? This is for an application we use that has a front end that does it; however, the bugs prevent us from doing anything and we are trying to now replicate same using backend.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your example data is correct? How do you deal with folder 1 with parent of folder 1?

Comment: I believe 1, 1 just points to 1. When I look at the application, the top most folder is 1 so that cannot have a parent.

Comment: It would be more logical to have it as NULL,1, but OK...

Comment: True but I am speaking based off the database that I am looking at. Just need a way to be able to list the entire folder path, up to its parent in a single line